# Proper PHP code to access MySQL database hosted by Arvixe

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have tried and cannot come to any success.  For the life of me, I cannot seem to connect to mySQL database on arvixe.com from my PHP file.  The name of my database is aerodial_database.  The table name is "test".  I am confused by the host name.  Arvixe support said the server hostname is dunlin.arvixe.com.  However, I have seen to simply use my domain name as the host name, and have seen other tutorials just use "localhost".  After I try to go to aerodial.com/myPHP.php, it gives me an error.  My question is, what is the proper PHP code in order to access my database on arvixe?  Thank you for any help.

```
<?php

$DB_HostName = “aerodial.com”;
$DB_Name = “aerodial_database”;
$DB_User = “aerodial_dbuser”;
$DB_Pass = “********”;
$DB_Table = “test”;

$Connect = mysql_connect($DB_HostName, $DB_User, $DB_Pass);

mysql_select_db(“$DB_Name”);

$name = $_GET[“name”];
$message = $_GET[“message”];


$query = “INSERT INTO $DB_Table (name, message)
VALUES (‘$name’, ‘$message’)”;
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Your database server can run on the same server but it doesn't have to. If you're hosting company gave you a different hostname to use for the database server, you will have to use that because it'd most likely a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <?php

    $DB_HostName = “localhost”;
    $DB_Name = “aerodial_database”;
    $DB_User = “aerodial_dbuser”;
    $DB_Pass = “********”;
    $DB_Table = “test”;

    $Connect = mysql_connect($DB_HostName, $DB_User, $DB_Pass);

    mysql_select_db(“$DB_Name”);

    $name = $_GET[“name”];
    $message = $_GET[“message”];


    $query = “INSERT INTO $DB_Table (name, message)
    VALUES (‘$name’, ‘$message’)”;
    mysql_query($query);

    mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to put host name as localhost.**

```
$DB_HostName = “localhost”;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a few check to do before trying something right. Is your website hosted on their server? If yes, don't look at my second point.

If no, you've to check if Arvixe allow `remote connection` to their database, if yes, then just check the host on their Help Center, if no, you'll be forced to host your website on their hosting service (which is what you're already doing in my opnion.)

Next thing is to forget `mysql_*` because it's deprecated, and move on to `PDO` (personnal preference, `mysqli` is fine too), just check with this code and give us the error, even if you should be able to see yourself what's the error is.

```
<?php
try {
    $DB_HostName = “aerodial.com”;
    $DB_Name = “aerodial_database”;
    $DB_User = “aerodial_dbuser”;
    $DB_Pass = “********”;
    $DB_Table = “test”;
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HostName;dbname=$DB_Name", $DB_user, $DB_Pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $DB_Table(name, message) VALUES(:name, :message)")
    ->execute([
        'name'    => $_GET['name'],
        'message' => $_GET['message']
    ]);
?>
```

For your question about which server, it really depend of the server configuration, they will most likely send you an email with the credentials you need to use, just stick to them. Tutoriel show you how to connect, but you don't have to follow them strictly, you've to adapt the code to match with your own configuration.

Comment: Man I really appreciate your help.  I'm using it with an iOS app and am not familiar with PHP and SQL so I am learning on the fly.  My website is hosted by arvixe as i updated the DNS to point to arvixe.  I just checked the email and there server info was indeed on there.  It looks like it is http://dunlin.arvixe.com/.  In my browser, to reach my PHP file, is this what I type in followed by /myPHP.php?  Or what should I type in my browser to access the php?  Thank you for bearing with me...

Comment: I changed my PHP file to use the code you left me.  I tried to access it using aerodial.com/myPHP.php but came up with this error Not Found

The requested URL /myPHP.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Your error come from something else than mysql, have you uploaded your file on the server, where do you put in on the ftp?

Comment: I'm an idiot an didn't upload it to my server.  I uploaded your exact code to my server under public_html.   So now instead of an error, aerodial.com/myPHP.php just brings up a blank white page.

Comment: Mean that it work correctly, I edited my answer with flul code

Comment: Progress made!  Getting this error though:      Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: It's probably not localhost, changed my first code, and you've to change "localhost" by "aerodial.com"

Comment: What is the next step to uploading data to my database after uploading the PHP file to my server?

Comment: Access to your page with the desired information, for example here: yourPage.php?name=NameToSave&message=YourMessage